# Using Wordpress CSS in plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

I was writing my first wordpress plugin, and I'm facing some problems in Styling it.
I know that i could use my own CSS file in my plugin, but I don't want that.
I want to use the same style which used in wordpress admin, my problem here, is there any documentation from wordpress about it's css ? i.e : if you want to use tabs you can simply write content here  or whatever.

Waiting your help.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is no current documentation on the CSS used within the WordPress admin and you'll have to pick it up by picking apart pages using an in-browser editor. (hit F12 on chrome to open it up).

There is this website: http://dotorgstyleguide.wordpress.com/ which shows some of the stylings used but its a bit out of date and hasn't been completed yet.

These are a couple of bits ive picked up.

```
// always wrap your code around a div with the class wrap to keep it contained
<div class="wrap">
</div>

// Use H2 for page titles. You can put icons before using icon32 or icon16 as the 
// class for its size and setting the id as what the name of the icon is
<div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>
<h2>Page Title</h2>

// Table format
<table class="form-table">
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="active">Form Label</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="active" maxlength="45" size="10" name="active" value="TRUE" />   
            <p class="description">Small description under box</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thats about as much as i can think of off the top my head. Sadly it is all about picking it apart and seeing what is useful and what is not. The bits above should give you a good starting point.

Comment: thank you @Rhys, i'll try to find any source. and for now i'm suing the inspect element, but I said maybe there is another way to avoid wasting my time.